# frame-step by 10 or 20 frames at once?

Tags: mpv

Hello I use MPV to help me with animations studies, its simply the best.

I want to ask is there away to `Step-Frame` forward\back by n amount of frames?

stepping forward by a single frame is ideal when you are where you want to be, but can slow otherwise. Yet seeking by seconds is too fast.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!